# Is it possible to add custom property to CActiveRecord in yii?

Tags: php, yii

After use

```
$model=Table::model()->findByPk($id);
```

We can use

```
$p=$model->property;
```

to get property value. This property is corresponding to a table column, but I hope add one new property for `$model` which is not table column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In your model after the

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{table}}".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table '{{table}}':
 * @property integer $id
 .......
 */
 class Table extends CActiveRecord
 {
```

part you can define custom properties for your class. Like this:

```
class Table extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $aPublicAttribute;
    private $_aPivateAttribute;
```

You can reference these just like you reference the attributes that exist in your table.